# Reading a users input after stopping timer?

Tags: c#, .net

Editing a tutorial online for a mini pacman game. There are some bugs i still need to fix but im having trouble getting user input. I want it to restart when the user presses the "r" key after a game over.

Ive tried taking in user input but that constantly crashes. So ive made a work around where it restarts on its own after game over or winning. With gameover it start one new window. If i win it spawns multiple windows. I know its because my foreach loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char restart;

    bool goup;
    bool godown;
    bool goleft;
    bool goright;

    int speed = 5;

    int ghost1 = 8;
    int ghost2 = 8;

    int ghost3x = 6;
    int ghost3y = 6;

    int score = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label2.Visible = false;
    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            goleft = true;
            pacman.Image = Properties.Resources.Left;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            goright = true;
            pacman.Image = Properties.Resources.Right;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            goup = true;
            pacman.Image = Properties.Resources.Up;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            godown = true;
            pacman.Image = Properties.Resources.down;
        }
    }

    private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            goleft = false;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            goright = false;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            goup = false;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            godown = false;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Score " + score;

        if (goleft)
        {
            pacman.Left -= speed;
        }

        if (goright)
        {
            pacman.Left += speed;
        }

        if (goup)
        {
            pacman.Top -= speed;
        }

        if (godown)
        {
            pacman.Top += speed;
        }

        redGhost.Left += ghost1;
        yellowGhost.Top += ghost2;

        if (redGhost.Width + redGhost.Left < 20 || redGhost.Right > ClientSize.Width - 1)
            ghost1 = -ghost1;

        if (yellowGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds))
            ghost2 = -ghost2;

        else if (yellowGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox5.Bounds))
            ghost2 = -ghost2;

        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if(x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "wall" || x.Tag == "ghost")
            {
                if(((PictureBox)x).Bounds.IntersectsWith(pacman.Bounds) || score == 30)
                {
                    pacman.Left = 0;
                    pacman.Top = 25;
                    label2.Text = "GAMEOVER";
                    label2.Visible = true;
                    timer1.Stop();


                    Application.Restart();
                }
            }

            if (x is PictureBox && x.Tag == "coin")
            {
                if (((PictureBox)x).Bounds.IntersectsWith(pacman.Bounds))
                {
                    this.Controls.Remove(x);
                    score++;
                }
            }
        }

        pinkGhost.Left += ghost3x;
        pinkGhost.Top += ghost3y;

        if(pinkGhost.Left < 1 ||
           pinkGhost.Left + pinkGhost.Width > ClientSize.Width -2 ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox5.Bounds))  ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox4.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox3.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)) || 
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds)))
        {
            ghost3x = -ghost3x;
        }

        else if(pinkGhost.Top < 1 || pinkGhost.Top + pinkGhost.Height > ClientSize.Height - 2 ||
            pinkGhost.Left + pinkGhost.Width > ClientSize.Width - 2 ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox5.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox4.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox3.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)) ||
           (pinkGhost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds)))
            ghost3y = -ghost3y;
    }

}
}
```

Id expect after the gameover for it to sit there with a gameover until I hit r or close the windows
It restarts automatically spawning a new screen. Ideally id just restart the game. Also Id like to be be able to use it based on user input instead of just after game over. 
If you win it spawns lots of new windows because the for each but once again ideally id like to just look for the user to enter "r"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could spawn a new Messagebox and wait for them to click ok.

```
DialogResult d = MessageBox.Show("Do you wanna Retry?", "delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (d == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
               //do something
            }
```

Comment: Thanks I considered looking into something along those lines. Though I feel that It's not quite what I want. For now I just restart the whole application upon victory or defeat. Thank you